# Transform integer values in a char column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I was trying to do transform some datasets in R when I found the following issue:
I have got a **char column** that shows the income of some people (a census). So what I was trying to do is to standardize the data for future analysis. This is a sample of the data:

| income |
| --- |
| 2000,3 Thousand Euros |
| 50,14 Thousand Euros |
| 54000 Euros |
| 52312 Euros |

This is what I am expecting:

| income |
| --- |
| 2000.3 k€ |
| 50.14 k€ |
| 54 k€ |
| 52.31 k€ |

And finally, this is the code I have got so far, but it still not working. I am new in R and I am still searching for methods. To clarify, in the ***if statement*** what I was trying is to search all those values that have more than 4 digits, but I think it is easier to search the ones which have " Euros". But to make operations, I believe I have to transform the char column into an integer one, so the " Euros" regex will not be valid (I believe).

```
    census$income <- str_replace_all(census$income, " Thousand Euros", '')
    census$income <- str_replace_all(census$income, " Euros", '')
    census$income <- as.integer(census$income)
    if(floor(log10(census$income))+1>4){
      census$income/1000
    }
    census$income <- as.character(census$income)
```

Thank you very much for any help! =)

Comment: Please provide a sample using `dput`. It seems, you also have to account for "," and encoding (EUR-sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with nested `sub`:

`dyplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(income = sub("(000\\s|\\sThousand\\s)?Euros", " k€", 
                      sub(",", ".", income)))
      income
1 2000.3 k€
2  50.14 k€
3     54 k€
```

`base R`:

```
df$income <- sub("(000\\s|\\sThousand\\s)?Euros", " k€", 
                 sub(",", ".", df$income))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  income = c("2000,3 Thousand Euros","50,14 Thousand Euros","54000 Euros")
)
```

**EDIT**:

Here's a solution for more complex data (as per OP's comment):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    # change comma into dot:
    income = gsub(",", ".", df$income),
    # remove text:
    income = gsub("[ A-Za-z]", "", income),
    # divide integer by 1000:
    income = ifelse(str_detect(income, "^\\d+$"),
                               as.numeric(str_extract(income, "\\d+"))/1000,
                    income),
    # add " k€":
    income = paste0(income, " k€"))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  income = c("2000,3 Thousand Euros","50,14 Thousand Euros","54000 Euros", "43156 Euros")
)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I think it is a really good answer, but I also have got some incomes like 43156 euros, so the sub method, would not apply to that number, because it does not end in 000. Do you know any other method? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see edited solution: step-by-step and tidy

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! I was struggling because I used your code but at the end I coded 'df' to show if it works but I saw it wasn't working, until I realized I did not need to use 'df' at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this with a combination of `readr::parse_number` and `str_detect(tolower(income), "thousand")`.

```
census %>% 
  mutate(
    parsed_income = if_else(
        str_detect(tolower(income), "thousand"), 
        parse_number(income), 
        1000 * parse_number(income)
    )
  )
```